# How to create one UNICODE_STRING from another UNICODE_STRING

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, unicode-string, wchar-t

Is there any better way to deep copy clone `UNICODE_STRING`?

This is what I tried.

```
int main()
{
    //This is what I have.
    UNICODE_STRING oldString = RTL_UNICODE_STRING("This is test string."); //ignore macro RTL_UNICODE_STRING

    //Some madeup things.
    std::wstring middleManString(oldString.Buffer, oldString.Length/sizeof(UNICODE_NULL));
    
    
    //This is what I am seeking.
    UNICODE_STRING newString;
    NTSTATUS status = RtlCreateUnicodeString(&newString, middleManString.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *RtlDuplicateUnicodeString*

Comment: Or `RtlUnicodeStringCopy()`, or `RtlUnicodeStringInit/Ex()` if the source `UNICODE_STRING` is null-terminated.

Comment: @RbMm Unable find the documentation of `RtlDuplicateUnicodeString` :(

Comment: @RemyLebeau `UNICODE_STRING ` is not null terminated. the functions you have mentioned does not create memory on heap. They might need preexisting memory.

Comment: @Mayur "*`UNICODE_STRING ` is not null terminated*" - it *can* be, but is not *required* to be, that is why I said IF. I never understood why Microsoft didn't make an init function that takes a length as input.

Comment: @Mayur look in *ntifs.h*. also what is unclear in this api ? in allocate memory for string and copy existing. constants for flags declared. also look https://codemachine.com/article_ten_kernel_apis.html

Comment: @Mayur Microsoft doesn't document `RtlDuplicateUnicodeString()`, but a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=RtlDuplicateUnicodeString) shows some 3rd party references for it.

Comment: Thank you @RbMm for `RtlDuplicateUnicodeString`. I was worried about it's not available msdn, but I'm able to find it in legacy code

Comment: microsoft declare `RtlDuplicateUnicodeString` in *ntfs.h*